# Determine The Encoding of a specific character in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, encoding, unicode, character-encoding

I'm having a problem with a generated document (coming from crystal reports engine). Initially hyphens are visible  but if the text is copied and pasted with "keep text only" option or "remove formatting option" the hyphen character gets changed to a blank space " ".

I'm quite sure this is an issue with the encoding of the character, is there a way for m to get the unicode code for a given character in word ?

Answer (score 2):

This does not appear to be about *encoding* but about the identity of a character. To determine the Unicode code number (code point) of a character, place the cursor right after it (i.e. click on the location between it and the next character), then press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>. This replaces the character by its hexadecimal four- or five-digit Unicode number. You can undo the change with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> as usual.

If <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> causes no change, then the symbol is not a character at all but an internal code of Word, just displayed graphically. For example, in the “Show All” mode Word shows a hyphenation hint as “¬”, but it’s not really any character.

**Update**. As I say in my answer to the [other formulation of this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076794/crystal-reports-improperly-encoding-hyphens-on-export-to-word) at StackOverflow, the things here is not really a character by the special code Nonbreaking Hyphen in Word. It looks like a hyphen, prevents line break after it, and turns to a space if copied and pasted as plain text.

Comment: I tried this and it is the latter so I suppose t is an internal word character.  Is there any way to force word to convert these to unicode ?

Comment: Maybe. We first need to know what it is. Some internal codes can be specified in the Find and Replace window.

Comment: Find and replace does not work.  It replaces all spaces in the document with '-'

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste the offending character into [Unicode Lookup](http://unicodelookup.com/).

I don't think you can specify alternate encoding within CR.

Comment: I have allready tried to paste the character in a unicode lookup and it comes up as blank, which makes me think it is not unicode encoded.

Comment: Brief survey indicates CR default is UTF8- can you confirm?

Comment: after version 9 is but there documentation is very who knows what the export is.  It seems that the character is indeed not unicode after using the alt-x command.